# Multiple dropdowns showing dynamic options and contains the name of directories from the system?

Tags: php, ajax, select, drop-down-menu, subdirectory

[Folder Structure present where my index.php is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVANb.png)
I have a webpage that creates directories (nested also) on the server (as of now in my system).

I want to have multiple select elements.

1st select element shows the folders present in Project/Department.
2nd select element shows the folders that are present in the folder selected in the 1st select element and so on.

I tried this with PHP but it only works with the 1st select element.    for the next select element it shows the contents of the last folder of the 1st select element.

As I create dynamic directories I wont be able to use arrays to fetch data.
I need the code to do the above job.

Thank you